# How to find the count/length of the elements inside an element?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<step name="step1">
    <select name="select6" label="Select 6">
        <option val="option1">Option 1</option>
        <option val="option2">Option 2</option>
        <option val="option3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" placeholder="enter text"></input>
</step>
```

I would like the total number of these elements inside the `<step>` element (i.e 2)

In Javascript, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just obtain the `step` element using `document.getElementsByName` and use the `childElementCount` method to obtain number of children.

```js
var stepElement = document.getElementsByName('step1');
console.log(stepElement[0].childElementCount);
```

```html
<step name="step1">
    <select name="select6" label="Select 6">
            <option val="option1">Option 1</option>
                    <option val="option2">Option 2</option>
                    <option val="option3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
     <input type="text" placeholder="enter text"/>
</step>
```

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `querySelector` and `children`

```
var childCount = document.querySelector( "[name='step1']" ).children.length
```

**Demo**

```js
var childCount = document.querySelector( "[name='step1']" ).children.length;

console.log(childCount);
```

```html
<step name="step1">
    <select name="select6" label="Select 6">
        <option val="option1">Option 1</option>
        <option val="option2">Option 2</option>
        <option val="option3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" placeholder="enter text">
</step>
```